# Public transport planning in Spain

Tags: public-transport, spain

Is there a comprehensive public transport planner for intercity transport (bus and / or train) in Spain?

From what I found so far it looks like some companies have their own planner, but obviously that wouldn't work when traveling with more than one company.

There is [alsa.es](https://www.alsa.es/) for instance, but it seems to be usable for direct connections only. An example: I can find both San Sebastian → Bilbao and Bilbao → Haro but not San Sebastian → Haro (either direct or via Bilbao). Also, it doesn't seem to have a schedule more than one month in advance.

I'm specifically interested in the Basque and Rioja regions. So, if no planner exists, it would also help to know which companies operate there.

Comment: Google Maps can usually plan journeys by public transportation reasonably well. I haven't personally used it in Spain, so I'm not posting this as a definite answer, just a suggestion.

Comment: When you say "*comprehensive*" are you including local services or are you really only interested in inter-city services?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good point, I'm interested in inter-city transport only. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Johanna Yeah, Google at least gives transfer information. So far I use Google first, and then go to the companies own site(s) for more specific information. It would be helpful though to know how reliable Google actually is in this area.

Comment: I've been testing Google maps in Catalonia, and as far as I can tell it's reasonably good but incomplete. At least, it can't find public transport routes to places where I know a bus exists - for example, for stops in the line http://www.teisa-bus.com/pdf/pdf_comarques_pdf84.pdf . I suppose Google hasn't got information from some transport companies.

Answer (score 1):

Having just returned from a trip to the Rioja and Basque regions, I'm pretty sure the answer is *No* (for those two regions at least).

As already mentioned in one of the comments, Google Maps is the best place to start searching, and for **train travel** it seems to be pretty comprehensive.

However, there are many **bus** lines that Google does not yet know about, and since there are a lot of different bus companies it can be difficult to find the information you need. Probably the best way is to go to the main bus station and ask at a ticket booth. Even if they sell tickets for one company only, they usually know about other departures as well. If they don't, or if you don't speak Spanish, look for printed sheets with departure information. Each company will have its own, and they may not be posted at the same location. The same information can usually be found as PDF on the companies home pages, but they don't always give a list of intermediate stops (just departure and destination).